# Confused about the meaning of zero conditional mean with regressions analysis /exogeneity)

Tags: regression, econometrics, conditional-expectation, notation, exogeneity

Usually the exogeneity assumption is states, given the vector E[$\epsilon$|x]=0.

what this implies then is E[$\epsilon_i$|x$_i$]=0  for all i. The individual notation part is what is confusing me.

What is the intuition for the individual notation? is $\epsilon_i$ a random variable for each i, or is it just one random variable $\epsilon$,who's realizations vary with the population?  are we taking the expectation over all values for individual i, or are we taking the expectation of the error across individuals?

Answer (score 0):

$\epsilon$ is a vector random variable, with one component for each observation; each $\epsilon_i$ is a univariate random variable.

I encourage you to use this to try to answer your other questions, and then post a comment in a few hours or days if you’re still confused.

Answer (score 0):

In econometrics, the first definition refers to *strict* exogeneity.
The second definition is for *contemporaneous* exogeneity.

The first implies the second but the second doesn't imply the first (contemporaneous is a weaker condition than strict, as the latter represents past, present and future independence).

You can find some useful details here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/247418/292958
https://www.statisticshowto.com/exogeneity/